# mod_rewrite remove sub directory from certain URLs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a situation where I'm trying to remove a subdirectory from certain URLS.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish

http://www.example.com/shop/some_product should go to http://www.example.com/some_product

But

I need http://www.example.com/shop/customer/account to stay the same.

So essentially I need to rewrite anything *shop/...* except *shop/customer/...* *shop/admin/...*

Here is what I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/customer
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/sales
RewriteRule ^/shop/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L]
```

Anyone have any advice here?

Comment: Looks fine, except that you are missing the initial `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: And whether that leading slash `^/` in the `RewriteRule` is correct depends on _where_ you put that rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks arkascha.

Turns out I had a couple problems. Here is what I ended up with:

in /shop/.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/(media|skin|js|customer|admin|sales|checkout)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1 [L]
```

I needed to not rewrite URLs matching a file or directory. Also, it seems that having /shop/ was a requirement for the RewriteCond, but would not work in the RewriteRule.